# [MyClassName copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, runtime-error, unrecognized-selector, copywithzone

I just implemented my class

```
@interface ExampleNestedTablesViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *projectModelArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *sectionContentDictionary;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ProjectModel *project1 = [[ProjectModel alloc] init];
    project1.projectName = @"Project 1";

    ProjectModel *project2 = [[ProjectModel alloc] init];
    project2.projectName = @"Project 2";
    if (!projectModelArray)
    {
        projectModelArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:project1, project2, nil];
    }

    if (!sectionContentDictionary)
    {
        sectionContentDictionary  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *array1     = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Task 1", @"Task 2", nil];
        [sectionContentDictionary setValue:array1 forKey:[projectModelArray objectAtIndex:0]]; // **this line crashed**.

    }
}
```

Here is my Project Model

```
@interface ProjectModel : NSObject

typedef enum
{
    ProjectWorking = 0,
    ProjectDelayed,
    ProjectSuspended,

} ProjectStatus;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger idProject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* projectName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* listStaff;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* projectTimer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) ProjectStatus projectStatus;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* listTask;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger limitPurchase;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* limitTime;
@end
```

And the output is: 
SDNestedTablesExample[1027:c07] -[ProjectModel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7562920.
I didn't know which problem. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the docs for `NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:` (note you should use `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`). Notice the expected type for the key. It must be of type `id<NSCopying>`. This means the key must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Since your keys are of type `ProjectModel`, the error is complaining since your `ProjectModel` class doesn't implement the required method of the `NSCopying` protocol - `copyWithZone:`.

Are you sure you want to use a `ProjectModel` object as the key? Doing so also means you need a sane implementation of the `isEqual:` and `hash` methods, in addition to `copyWithZone`.

The solution is to update your `ProjectModel` class so it conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol and implements the `copyWithZone:` method. And also properly implement the `isEqual:` and `hash` methods. Or change the key to be just the `idProject` property (properly wrapped as an `NSNumber`).